# Update theme table using callback function in Ajax

Tags: forms, theming, ajax

I have two elements in my form: a select and a table element. Everytime onchange event is triggered on select element, I want to update the values in my table. I want to do query and change the values of '#rows' in the table.

```
function myid_print_user_page_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();
    $form['myid_print']['option'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',        
        '#options' => array(
            0 => t('All'),
            1 => t("Printed ID's"),
            2 => t("Unprinted ID's"),
        ),
        '#default_value' => 0,             
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'myid_print_all_submitted_id_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'myid_table_wrapper',
        ),                             
    );

    // Build the sortable table header.
    $header = array(
        'id_number' => array('data' => t('ID Number'), 'field' => 'id_number','sort' => 'asc'),     
        'student' => array('data' => t('Student'), 'field' => 'student', 'sort' => 'asc')
    );

    //Get the node data. 

    $query = db_select('student', 't1',array('target' => 'import'));
    $result = $query
        ->fields('t1', array('studid','lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'extname'))   
        ->condition('t1.id_status',1,'=')
        ->distinct()
        ->execute();

    //Build the rows.
    $rows = array();  
    foreach($result as $record){
        $rows[$record->studid] = array(
            'id_number' => $record->studid,
            'student' => $record->firstname . ' ' . $record->middlename . ' ' . $record->lastname . ' ' . $record->extname,    
        );
    }

    //Build the table 
    $form['table'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => $header,
        '#rows' => $rows,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="myid_table_wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    return $form;
}
```

I'm stuck here, I don't know what to put in my callback function.

```
function myid_print_all_submitted_id_callback($form, $form_state)
{
    //Do query here and put the query results in the table.
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of the form elements using the $form_state parameter. So when you have the value of the select element, you can perform the query as required, build the table using [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) and return the result. The returned result can be replaced or appended to the ajax wrapper defined in your form.